# Aws Amplify Auth Rule not working as expected

Tags: authentication, graphql, aws-amplify

Hello i want that every authenticated user can create, update, read, delete OrgReg objects.

But read only his own objects, no one should be able to read (see) other objects from other users. Only the group admins should be able to do everthing.

To visualize: I have a screen, the owner should be able to see his object, but not other objects, and the group should be see all objects from the OrgReq model.

I thought i can realize that with this code:

```
type OrgReq
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }, { allow: groups, groups: ["admins"] }]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  street: String!
  zip: String!
  city: String!
  phoneNumber: String!
  state: String!
  userID: ID!
  accepted: Boolean
  description: String
}
```

But it does not work, i can still see from other the objects.
Anyone whoe can give me a hint?